# Want to only build specific submodules of a maven project

Tags: maven, module, pom.xml

I have a multi module maven project with multiple levels of directory heirarchy. Normally we build the whole project, but have hit some resource issues building docker images (these are orchestrated from the maven modules), and a workaround is to create multiple build jobs, each of which builds a single image.

One option is to simply cd to the relevant subdirectory and build from there, but I would ideally like to use the 'mvn -pl' option, though am struggling with the useage

We use groupid 'org.odpi.egeria' & The pom is structured as

```
 . (egeria)
   open-metadata-resources (open-metadata-resources)
     open-metadata-deployment (open-metadata-deployment)  
       docker (open-metadata-docker)
         egeria (open-metadata-docker-egeria)
```

This is just one part of the tree to demonstrate the issue

Using the -pl option specifying directory names to build

Using the -pl option specifying artifacts to build

```
mvn -pl open-metadata-resources/open-metadata-deployment/docker/egeria  clean install
```

```
mvn -pl org.odpi.egeria:open-metadata-docker-egeria clean install
```

In both cases I get:

```
[ERROR] [ERROR] Could not find the selected project in the reactor: open-metadata-resources/open-metadata-deployment/docker/egeria @
[ERROR] Could not find the selected project in the reactor: open-metadata-resources/open-metadata-deployment/docker/egeria -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: A colleague pointed out the rather simpler way is to use
```
mvn -f open-metadata-resources/open-metadata-deployment/docker clean install
```
This should work in this case, but still intrigued as to the pl option

Comment: If you like to use `-pl` option you have to install the whole project once in your local cache via `mvn clean install` afterwards you can use `-pl ..`...